# How to launch a few GitHub self-hosted runners instances from an image?

Tags: github-actions

I prepared a golden image for self-hosted runners, using

```
./config.sh --url https://github.com/my-organization--token XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But I can run only one instance, the second one fails with

```
ERR  MessageListener] GitHub.DistributedTask.WebApi.TaskAgentSessionConflictException: The actions runner my-label already has an active session
```

How I can run a few instances from my image?

Comment: Have you tried with another token?

Comment: @frennky - I haven't tried, I guess sit will work.
I just assumed that it's possible to prepare a golden image for my self-hosted runner and just launch a few instances from that image.

Comment: The token is also short lived. Not sure how long, but either way it wouldn't make sense to bake it in. There is an API call you can make to request for a token, then you could run a config script with it.

Comment: Right, token is short-lived. I use that token into 'setup.sh' just to activate runner. After that I have a "permanent" runner.